# Applying groupBy to Spring specification query

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm building a simple search engine using Spring specification-driven repositories. The problem is that i make joinful queries which end in duplicating records, and i need to apply a groupBy restriction, which isn't applied to resulting query if i call `.groupBy` in my specification. How can i achieve such grouping?

The minimal example may be specified as follows:

*Repository*

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

public interface EntityRepository implements JpaSpecificationExecutor<Entity> {}
```

*Specification*

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

public class DummyEntitySpecification implements Specification<Entity> {
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Entity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery,
            CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        // So from here i get results with repeated main entity data, but actually
        // i need to filter results that has presence of related subentities of
        // some sort
        From join = root.join("SubEntity");
        // though i call groupBy here, Spring internally uses another query
        // instance, which doesn't inherit grouping
        criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get("id"));
        return criteriaBuilder.ge(join.get("id"), 1);
    }
}
```

*Call*

```
public class Anyclass {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    public void uselessSearch() {
        // this may return several entities with id = 1, for example
        entityRepository.findAll(new DummyEntitySpecification());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand exactly how you are doing your queries at all. Could you provide some code showing it?

Comment: @LucasSaldanha i've added simple example, feel free to ask about more detailed explanation